# match url regexp for subfolder on IIS 7 with web.config

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, web-config

I am using get simple cms on my ISS server (actually have to use ISS) and there is a plugin to enable rewrite on ISS with `web.config`.

web.config source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="GetSimple Fancy URLs" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([^/]+)/?$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="?id={R:1}" />
            </rule>
     </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

but my CMS on both main folder `/` and sub folder `/en` such as:

http://domainname.com/ (main cms)
http://domainname.com/en/ (another cms on subfolder)

with the `web.config` above, main cms working successfully but the cms on subfolder not working (gives 404 as before did)

how can I implement that subfolder rule to `web.config file`? so 2 cms working successully.

I tried to place same web.config file under subfolder (`/en`) but it did not work.

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your regular expression will only match URL's that are virtually in the root of your website, e.g. `domain.com/page` or `domain.com/anotherpage`. It will not match sub-directories like `domain.com/subdir/page`. But that might be just what you want, I don't know.

To make it work with `/en` as well, change the rule to:

```
<rule name="GetSimple Fancy URLs" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(en/)?([^/]+)/?$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}?id={R:2}" />
</rule>
```

If you want a more generic solution that will work for any two character language code, use this:

```
<rule name="GetSimple Fancy URLs" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^([a-z]{2}/)?([^/]+)/?$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}?id={R:2}" />
</rule>
```

This should be just in the `web.config` in your root directory.